# How to replicate the default iOs Safari share preview and functionality with Navigator.share()?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, mobile-safari

We have the following URL:

https://phmuseum.com/awards/bredaphoto-festival-open-call-2024

If we navigate to that URL in iOs Safari and click the bottom middle browser share icon we get the following share preview:

[image]

If we then share to the Notes app we get a link preview. This is ideal and what we are looking to replicate with Navigator.share().

With navigator.share variations we get the following previews:

**Title + URL**

```
navigator.share({
     title: 'BredaPhoto Festival Open Call 2024',
     url: 'https://phmuseum.com/awards/bredaphoto-festival-open-call-2024',
});
```

[image]

If we then share to the notes app we get a link preview, ideal.

**URL**

```
navigator.share({
     url: 'https://phmuseum.com/awards/bredaphoto-festival-open-call-2024',
});
```

[image]

If we then share to the notes app we get a link preview, ideal.

**Text**

```
navigator.share({
     text: 'https://phmuseum.com/awards/bredaphoto-festival-open-call-2024',
});
```

[image]

If we then share to the notes app we only get the link as text, not ideal.

Anyway to get closer to the default functionality?